# Get Azure product list without subscription id

Tags: azure, product

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/?product=all

When am trying hit this API call am getting response in a html format why it is like that?

If we want response in JSON format what is the solution?

What is the steps I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a response in JSON format, simply use Postman to access the API call URL.

In Postman, you can select the language of the response accordingly on your requirements.

**URL:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/?product=all

**Method:** GET

**Authorization**: Bearer Token

***Output:***

[image]

***Output in*** `JSON` ***Format***:

[image]